# Understanding "cat /proc/net/udp"

Tags: linux, networking, udp, sockets

```
cat /proc/net/udp | egrep "sl|3ADBFE0A"
   sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode   ref pointer drops
   16: 3ADBFE0A:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    74        0 40124    2 f203ca80 0
  509: 3ADBFE0A:0868 00000000:0000 07 00008C00:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 79208333 2 ea226340 0
```

I would like to seek for deeper and more beginner-friendly explanation of the fields of the `cat /proc/net/udp` output,
especially the `tx_queue`.

From the [proc(5) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> `/proc/net/udp`
>
>   Holds a dump of the UDP socket table. 
>   Much of the information is not of use apart from debugging. 
>   The "sl" value is the kernel hash slot for the socket,
>   [and] the "local_address" is the local address and port number pair. 
>   The "rem_address" is the remote address and port number pair
>   (if connected). 
>   "St" is the internal status of the socket. 
>   The "tx_queue" and "rx_queue" are
>   the outgoing and incoming data queue in terms of kernel memory usage. 
>   The "tr", "tm->when", and "rexmits" fields
>   are not used by UDP. 
>   The "uid" field
>   holds the effective UID of the creator of the socket.

If I am correct with my understanding that when this `tx_queue` value is greater than 0 meaning that there are more packets that are waiting to be sent and that the application is not fast enough to send those packets?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753306/meaning-of-fields-in-proc-net-udp

Answer (score 1):

If `tx_queue` is greater than 0, then it is the OS that cannot deliver packets as fast as the sending application is trying to send them. I guess it could also mean that [Ethernet Flow Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_flow_control) is at work. In any event, the sending application is not the culprit.

The actual value in `tx_queue` will be hexadecimal.